# "I have ever been to New York. "Is this sentence correct?

Tags: negation, licensing

I'm not a native english speaker.
I know this sentence is correct.

Have you ever been to New York? (O)
I have never been to New York. (O)

I have ever been to New York. <<<< ???
Is this sentence correct in grammar? or possible? or natural?

Comment: Something like *"I've been to New York once."* would sound better.

Answer (score 3):

In short, "ever" cannot be used to make an assertion, but rather to ask a question, or an embedded question (wh-clause).

For instance

> He is asking me **whether** I have ever been to New York.
>
> Have I **ever** been to New York? I don't think so. I have **never** been to New York.

The wh-clause "**whether** I have ever been to New York" cannot be used by itself; it is dependent on another clause.

Also note that we can make a statement with "ever", if it is negative. This is based on the principle that "never" can be regarded as a condensation of "not ever"

> I have **not ever** been to New York.

Finally, structures like "have I ever been ..." are possible, if they express irony or emotive emphasis. For instance, "Boy, have I ever been cheated!"

This could somehow apply to New York.

> A: Have you been to New York?
>
> B: Have I **ever** been to new York! I spent three weeks there just last year and actively explored the city for something like ten hours a day.

Answer (score 2):

<sub>Sorry for the technical jargon.</sub>

The word *ever* is a [negative polarity item](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarity_item) (NPI), and can only be used in contexts which license NPIs:

- negative declarative clauses ("I have not ever been to New York")
- interrogative clauses ("Have you ever been to New York?")
- conditional clauses ("If you ever go to New York")

You cannot use NPIs in positive declarative clauses, so *"I have ever been to New York" is not grammatical.

[Huddleston & Pullum](http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/languages-linguistics/grammar-and-syntax/cambridge-grammar-english-language) have a footnote on *never* and *ever* at the bottom of page 823:

> *Never* is likely to be preferred over verbal negation when *ever* immediately follows *not* or the negative verb; a more natural use of frequency *ever* is seen in *I don't think he ever loses his patience*. *Ever* can be used in juxtaposition to *never* with emphatic effect; this device is associated primarily with informal conversation, but can be found in other styles too: *Any risk of a prime minister abusing this power is effectively eliminated because he can never, ever put a political crony into the job*.

Answer (score 1):

The word *ever* is used to describe *at any time*.

> "Have you ever been to New York?"

Means, at any given point of time, have you (ever) visited the state? This can be answered -

> No, I have never been to New York. OR *Yes, I have been to New York [preferably with number of times since it has the word *ever*]. Even shorter answer is - *No, never* or *Oh yes, thrice.*

*I have ever been to New York* as a response to that question does not sound okay to me.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to answer the way the question is put, here, for the question Have you ever been to New York? (O) I have never been to New York. (O) is a negative answer, and right usage.

But, you cannot use "ever" instead of "never" and say "I have ever been to New York." That is not even a possible answer for a positive reply.  Nevertheless, you may use, "I have been to New York" , to say that you have gone to New York, or you can mention number of times you have visited and so on